# How replace unique string include some characters Before with an increment Number

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Here is my string :

> ...
>   ...
>   ...8451__Same_String__...
>   ...5236__Same_String__...
>   ...9854__Same_String__...
>   ...8751__Same_String__...
>   ...3254__Same_String__...
>   ...
>   ...

Dots mean -> other characters in my string.
As you see there are 5 same SubStrings in my string that i want to change 4 digits number before all of those same SubStrings with an increment number!
Mean after changes (using with **remove** or **replace** or **regex** or whatever) i want this string :

> ...
>   ...
>   ...1111__Same_String__...
>   ...2222__Same_String__...
>   ...3333__Same_String__...
>   ...4444__Same_String__...
>   ...5555__Same_String__...
>   ...
>   ...

As you see **Same_String** is not my goal and my goal is those 4 digits numbers that should change like this : 1111 ,2222 ,3333 ,4444 ,5555 ,...

How can i do that?

Comment: How do you identify the position of Same_String ? Is it fixed ?

Comment: The question was about the "IndexOf" the string in the line. May you confirm that SameString is not variable, i.e. a unique string not changed when looping on lines ? Is the count always lower than 10 ?

Comment: Same_String -> "Hi , stackoverflow members." i have 5 of them in my big string. so what is your mean is it fixed? the answer is yes. Same_String is not a variable and it's a string as i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regex,

```
int count = 0;
var result = Regex.Replace(
               text, 
               @"\d\d\d\d(__Same_String__)", 
               m => (++count).ToString().PadLeft(4, (char)(count + '0')) + m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: thanks. please start count from 1111 and do n't use ++!

Comment: @MoonLight It starts with 1111 and why should I not use ++ ? Have you tested the code? I did before posting.

Comment: Hi @EZI, great answer! I was just ready to post my (working) 10-liner but your's is just adorable!